# Run tests in different browser sessions but always get 'NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?'

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng, pageobjects

My test project has @BeforeClass and @AfterClass in the BaseTest.class:

```
public class BaseTest {

  @BeforeClass(groups = {"first"})
  public void beforeTest() {
    getDriver().get("URL");
  }

  @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
  public void afterTest() {
    getDriver().close();
    removeDriver();
  }
}
```

and its FirstTest.Class:

```
public class SmokeTest extends BaseTest {

  private PageOne pageOne = PageFactory.initElements(getDriver(), PageOne.class);
  @Test(testName = "test1", groups = { "first" })
  public void firstTest() {
    pageOne.goSomething();
  }

  @Test(testName = "test2", groups = { "first" })
  public void secondTest() {
    pageOne.goSomethingElse();
  }
}
```

WebDriver singleton:

```
public class WebDriverSingleton {

  private static WebDriver driver;

  public static WebDriver getDriver() {
    if (driver == null) {
      driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
    return driver;
  }

  public static void removeDriver() {
    driver.quit();
    driver = null;
  }
}
```

And it works just fine. Until I have added new cases which I'd like to start in a new browser instances.

What I've added:

```
public class BaseModuleTest {
  @BeforeClass(groups = {"second"})
  public void beforeClass() {
    getDriver().get("another URL");
  }
}
```

```
public class ModuleTest extends BaseModuleTest {

  private PageTwo pageTwo = PageFactory.initElements(getDriver(), PageTwo.class);
  private PageOne pageOne = PageFactory.initElements(getDriver(), PageOne.class);

  @Test(testName = "test1", groups = {"second"})
    public void testUp() {
      pageTwo.goToPageOne();
      pageOne.doSomething(); // getting fail here
  }
}
```

When I start test using testgnconfiguration.xml

1. 'first' group passes
2. browser window closes
3. new instance of WebDriver opens new browser window
4. goes to URL
5. when starts interacting with the first WebElement on the page that was instantiated during 'first' group run returns an error:

   > > > org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?

So far as I'm using the Page Object Model and I'm using in the 'second' group the same Pages which has been initialised in the 'first' group, I guess they somehow 'remember' the first Session Id which became 'null'.
Although I reinitialise them in ModuleTest.test1()...

Anyway if my suggestions are correct, how to pass a new sessionId to instantiated page objects? Or what is proper way to reinitialise them?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem is:

```
@BeforeClass(groups = {"first"})
```

and

```
@AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
```

You are always destroying the driver object after finishing with a class, but you are only creating a driver object for a class in a specific group.  I would suggest tweaking your `@BeforeClass` to:

```
@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
```

or

```
@BeforeClass(groups = {"first, "second"})
```

Comment: Tried it. Actually I've tried many configs of ```@Before``` and ```@After``` combinations. And have no success :(
The root cause within 'old' page object has 'old' sessionId I guess...

Comment: How are you getting the driver object inside your tests?  Your description above sounds like you are referencing the wrong driver object.

Comment: Just using static getDriver();

Comment: Is your PageObject also using the static getDriver(); ?

Comment: Yep. I've updated description. Check it out please.

Comment: Hmm I still think `@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)` should work.  It looks like you are defining your Page Objects outside of the @Test annotation so the @BeforeClass may not always be triggering correctly, especially since the groups tag is on a test, not a class.

Comment: Lets try :)
But what ```@BeforeClass``` (I have two with different URLs) should have ```alwaysRun = true```? Or both of them?

Comment: Hard to answer without seeing how all the code hangs together to be honest.  If the @BeforeClass is linked to a specific test class you don't really need the groups, so you should be able to modify both instances.